# Python Selenium : Wait to start checking if statement

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browser, webdriver, browser-automation

I have built a script to login to my local Unifi Camera access through the IP.
It all works in a loop, as it sometimes fails and goes back to the beginning and I want it to keep checking to repair itself.

I am only stuck on one part, the last part. I have it checking if there is an error, and if so, it refreshes the page and will then recognize the fullscreen class again and proceed;

```
    if driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'has-message'):
        driver.refresh()
```

My issue is that when the page starts, error messages (has-message) initially appear as the camera page loads, so it recognizes that as an error and reloads the page. How do I make the if statement wait for a minute or so before checking if has-message class is on page?

I am quite new, but I have read a lot of documentation and have been stuck on this for a while. I don't usually ask on here, as I enjoy the struggle. Thank you for your assistance.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome("**%path%**/chromedriver.exe")
script_active = True

driver.get("https://%url%/login")
driver.maximize_window() # For maximizing window

while script_active:
    if driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#enhanced-protection-message'):
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "details-button").click()
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "proceed-link").click()
        print("SUCCESS : SECURITY BYPASS")
        sleep(5)
    if driver.find_elements("name", 'username'):
        driver.find_element("name", "username").send_keys("%username%")
        driver.find_element("name", "password").send_keys("%password%")
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='submit']").click()
        print("SUCCESS : LOG IN")
        sleep(3)
    if driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'mainSubView--cameras'):
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ubnt-icon--live-view").click()
        print("SUCCESS : SWITCH TO LIVE VIEW")
        sleep(3)
    if driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ubnt-icon--fullscreen'):
        try:
            driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ubnt-icon--fullscreen").click()
            sleep(10)
            print("SUCCESS : FULLSCREEN LIVE VIEW")
        except:
            print("STATUS : ALREADY LIVE VIEW")
    if driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'has-message'):
        driver.refresh()
```

Comment: Your check for 'has-message' is at the end of the script, why is that a problem? Is 'has-message' visible when the page is loading? Does it contain an error message? You need to find an element that is visible once the page is done loading and then wait for that to appear. Look into [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for help waiting.

Comment: @JeffC yes, has-message is the class that I need to check for, as it is basically an error message. Although, when page is loading initially, the has-message ("Slow connection") error appears.

Right now, I found this solution but I think there is a better way.
if driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'has-message'):
        print("NOTICE : FOUND ERROR MESSAGE - WILL SLEEP THEN CHECK")
        sleep(60)
        if driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'has-message'):
            print("NOTICE : FOUND ERROR MESSAGE - REFRESHING")
            driver.refresh()

Answer (score 0):

Since the messages panel always seems to contain some sort of message, you could write some code to handle the various messages,

```
messages = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'has-message')
if messages:
    if messages[0].text != "Slow connection":
        driver.refresh()
```

We're using `.find_elements()` to see if an element exists while avoiding exception checks. If an element is found, we check the text of the element and compare it to known error messages and then handle them. In this case, I've just made a generic handler where if the message is anything other than "Slow connection", we refresh the page. You can tweak this/add to this based on what message you want to handle differently.

---

Another option is to use a custom wait to wait for the element to NOT contain the text "Slow connection",

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(lambda d: d.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'has-message').text != "Slow connection")
```

Now you can set the timeout to whatever and the code will wait until the error message changes or it times out.